# AJAX request not working unless alert() is used

Tags: javascript, http, httprequest, chart.js

I'm making http- requests to get some information and show them in a bar chart. It is not working unless I include `alert(" ")`

Almost everything works fine, but without `alert()` the chart doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

```
app.controller('StatisticsCtrl', function ($scope, GitHubService) {


    // funktioniert - Test
    var getFollowedTmp = 0;
    var getFollowersTmp = 0;
    var getStarredTmp = 0;//Favoriten

    GitHubService.getFollowed(function (data) {
        getFollowedTmp = data.length;
    });
    GitHubService.getFollowers(function (data) {
        getFollowersTmp = data.length;
    });
    GitHubService.getStarred(function (data) {
        getStarredTmp = data.length;
    });


    alert("");
    var ctx = document.getElementById("profChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Followers", "Following", "Starred"],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Quantity',//Anzahl
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,51,48,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(0,51,48,0.2)",
                borderWidth: 1,             
                data: [getFollowersTmp, getFollowedTmp, getStarredTmp]
            }]
        },

        options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: do the things in teh callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work without the `alert` is because the `GitHubService` calls are async so the data isn't there by the time you render your chart.

The reason it works with `alert` is because `alert` pauses the execution (which to be fair is a little magic) so by the time you dismiss the alert the requests have completed.

You'll need to wait for the three GitHub service calls to complete before rendering the chart.

This could be achieved like this:

```
function tryRender() {
    if (getFollowedTmp && getFollowersTmp && getStarredTmp) {
         var myChart = new Chart(...);
    }
}

GitHubService.getFollowed(function (data) {
    getFollowedTmp = data.length;
    tryRender();
});
GitHubService.getFollowers(function (data) {
    getFollowersTmp = data.length;
    tryRender();
});
GitHubService.getStarred(function (data) {
    getStarredTmp = data.length;
    tryRender();
});
```

However that isn't overly elegant. If your `GitHubService` calls return [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (Many ajax libraries do) you could do:

```
Promise.all([
    GitHubService.getFollowed(),
    GitHubService.getFollowers(),
    GitHubService.getStarred()
]).then(function(result) {
    var getFollowedTmp = result[0].length;   
    var getFollowersTmp = result[1].length;
    var getStarredTmp = result[2].length;
    var myChart = new Chart(...);
});
```

Comment: i like your 1st solution. good work around, if we're not using promises.

Comment: i try it like this it do not work :

Comment: The first solution will only work if each GitHubService returns data, if it returns an empty array it'll still fail. It might therefore be better to maintain a 'getFollowedCompleted', 'getFollowersCompleted' or 'getStarredCompleted' flag separate from the data.

Answer (score 3):

methods in GitHubService are async. When you call alert(""), you're blocking execution from  going to the next line and thus giving the git hub service time to run and return.

Here's an example of chaning with Jquery. Other js frameworks, will have similar concepts.

```
var task1  = $.getJSON("http://resourceUri");
var task2  = $.getJSON("http://resourceUri2");

$.when(task1, task2).done(function(task1Response, task2Response){
   var task1Result = task1Response[0];
   var task2Result = task2Response[0];

   //Do something with the data. Charting?
});
```

Comment: so what i need to do?

Comment: Along KMC's answer I would wrap your service calls in a promise and then on success bind the items to the UI

Comment: so with rlcrews's comment, can you see what's returned when you invoke GitHubService.getStarred()? if it's a promise object (ref jquery api), you can do function chaining. For ex) GitHubService.getStarred().done(function(){ //do something})

Comment: oh, is GitHubService you're own abstraction or part of GitHub?

Comment: if you don't want to invest time in learning the concept of "promise" and deferred objects, you can look at "riscarrott" solution at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

One of the usual reasons that "removing blocking calls breaks my code" is because the blocking call gives time for the browser to load resources.

In your case I believe that `getFollowersTmp, getFollowedTmp, getStarredTmp` are not initialized in time.

One of the ways to solve it is to use [AngularJS's `$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to make sure all dependencies are loaded before continuing.

Comment: Ha, downvoted without any explanation.

Comment: i am new in javascript how can i initializ the funktions?

Comment: @thenewOne1234567890 [Chain the promises](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/), and only executes the rest of the code until all 3 calls to `GitHubService` are completed.